# Submit a login page in script

Tags: html, powershell

I am trying to automate login into a admin website. There are basically three things.

a) Username (implemented by getelementbyid)

b) Password (implemented by getelementbyid)

But for Login button I am lost.

Here is HTML code for Login :

onclick="$('form').submit();" class="button">Login<

I tried using getElementbyClassName(button) but I get following Error

HTMLElementClass does not contain a method named 'getElementbyClassName' in Powershell window
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you have written so far?

Comment: An example here: http://scriptolog.blogspot.be/2007/01/automated-web-forms.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) I am going to assume that you want to know how to fill out and submit a web form from powershell.

If you use the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet, and pass the address of the login form as the -URI parameter you can then see the forms, input fields, and submit buttons.

Example:

```
$myVar = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://someSite.com/login";
```

Now you can see the forms by looking at the contents of `$myVar.Forms`. You can fill the fields in like this

```
$myVar.Forms[indexOfFormOrFormNameInQuotes].Fields.field_name = "whatever"
```

You can now pass this filled out form in the body of the next request.

```
$nextRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://someSite.com/login" -body $myVar.Forms[indexOfFormOrFormNameInQuotes] -method Post
```

The last part, `-method Post`, ensures that the form is submitted, so you do not have to interact with the button on the form.

Comment: Normally I would not suggest an answer that is completely different from the solution being tried, however in this case it requires so little code I thought it would be appropriate.